# Resuming and working through an array "loop" in obj-C

Tags: objective-c, arrays, loops, resume

I'm writing an app where a group of people must mark each other. So I have a "Users" array like this:

```
0: paul
1: sally
2: james
3: bananaman
```

The first item Paul is marked (out of ten) by the other three, and then the second item Sally is marked by the other three (index 2, 3, 0) and so on, to create a "Results" array like this one:

```
0: paul, sally, 5
1: paul, james, 7
2: paul, bananaman, 9
3: sally, james, 4
```

I'm keeping track of the current 'scorer' and 'being_scored' integers as a new score gets added, which looks like this:

```
scorer = 1, being_scored = 0
scorer = 2, being_scored = 0
scorer = 3, being_scored = 0
scorer = 0, being_scored = 1
scorer = 2, being_scored = 1
```

However the group can stop scoring at any point, and a different group session could be loaded, which was also partially scored.

My question is how can I generate the 'scorer' and 'being_scored' values based only on the results [array count].

Presumably it's the [results count] divided by [users count] - 1, with the resulting whole number 'being_scored' and the remainder is the 'scorer'.

But my brain is utterly fried after a long week and this doesn't seem to be working.

Any help much appreciated

Mike.

Comment: I don't understand the results array. How can Paul be in the first element if he is being scored? Why are there two names although three are scoring? How is the number calculated?

Comment: The results array is multi-dimensional, the scored, the scorer and the score. So there will be three score entries given to paul, three for sally, etc.

Comment: Work out what the minimum amount of information is to be able to reconstruct and reload a scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Ignoring** your added comment that the "Results" array is multi-dimensional and simply contains structs/objects with three fields/properties: scored, scorer, score; then surely you just go to the last element of "Results" (at index `[Results count]-1`), select the scored and scorer and move on to the next in your sequence - which you presumably have logic for already in the case the loop was not interrupted (something like "if last scorer precedes being_scored [treating the array as a circular buffer by using modulo arithmetic] then advanced being_scored and init scorer else advance scorer").

But then that sounds rather obvious, but you did say you brain was fried...

**Not Ignoring** your added comment implies you have a two-dimensional array of scores which you are filling up in some pattern? If this is a pre-allocated array of some number type then if you init it with an invalid score (negative maybe?) you scan the array following your pattern looking for the first invalid score and restart from there. If it is a dynamic single dimensional array of single dimensional arrays then the `count` of the outer one tells you the being_scored, and the `count` of the last inner one tells you the scorer...

But that sounds rather obvious as well...

*Maybe some sleep? Then reframe the question if you're still stuck? Or maybe this bear of little brain missed the point entirely and somebody else will figure out your question for you.*

[This is more a comment than an answer, but its too long for a comment, sorry.]

Comment: Hello! Many thanks. I took the last element in the array and generated the 'scorer' id and 'being scored' id from that.